# Image Magick will not purge

Tags: imagemagick

I have a similar problem on double - boot windows 10 / Ubuntu (originally windows 7/windows 10 / ubuntu...
I started to get notices in the log that Image Magick was in a 'bad confiiguration state' so I used apt-remove to remove it... The icon was removed, so I assume so was the software, but now there seems to be glitch in auto updates (which may be looking for the original image magick I had just removed).. Maybe re-downloading and re-installing image magick might work? (I like the program, if configuration issues can be worked out...)---I've tried downloading it again but it loads without working... has anyone been able to resolve ??

Comment: Removing image magick from a desktop system is a bad idea. A lot of things depend on it. My 2 cents - reinstall it if you can.

Comment: Edit your question and include complete details.  You should include the exact steps you are taking with the complete command and also the entire verbatim output of each error, alongside the steps needed to reproduce each error.  By paraphrasing everything into your own words you are forcing us to guess at the problem and leaving out all of the essential diagnostic information that errors provide.  I also agree with @Organic that you shouldn't purge this package. Perhaps this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?

Comment: Packages that are in a *'bad confiiguration state'* sometimes need to be repaired or reinstalled before they can be successfully deleted. Please read your output carefully -- it will often tell you exactly what needs to be done. Since you have summaried the error messages, you have omitted most of the details we need to offer useful advice. Please edit your question to show complete output instead of summaries.